# How to give the right permissions to jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on an ubuntu server. Jenkins is under tomcat6, with all files belonging to the user and group tomcat6.

When I ask jenkins to update a directory using svn before building a job, it seems to have right access problem. The directory I try to upload belongs to the group www-data which contains the user tomcat6. I set the rights 775 on it, and I get the error below. If I set the rights 777, it works just fine.

How can I know which user does jenkins uses to do the svn update, and give it the correct rights, as it seems that it isn't tomcat6 ?

```
ERROR: Failed to update svn+ssh://myserver/myrepository
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200030: READONLY
```

Comment: Have you given Jenkins an SSH private key to use for the ssh+svn? Which user does that map to on the server? You may also be able to see the svn log in in /var/log/security.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Yes I did add the SSH key I previously generated to Jenkins. The user of this key is me, I just tried adding it to www-data group, it still doesn't work.
I don't have the folder security under /var/log, and I don't see any svn folder in there, is there a way to find it elsewhere ?

Comment: My mistake: looks like it's the file auth.log in /var/log that you want. You should see "Accepted publickey for tomcat6 from 1.2.3.4" or similar. (and I typoed - I meant 'see svn login' not an svn log)

Comment: I get the following in the auth.log, but there is no mention of tomcat6 !

    `Apr 15 14:35:24 paris sshd[18445]: Accepted publickey for userme from 192.168.1.200 port 44746 ssh2
    Apr 15 14:35:24 paris sshd[18445]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userme by (uid=0)
    Apr 15 14:35:24 paris svnserve: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free`

Comment: OK, that was assuming that the SSH key was attached to user tomcat6. It looks like it's authenticating as `userme` then.

Comment: So what can I do ? It seems that joining `userme` to the group of the folder doesn't authorize jenkins to do the update using svn

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did found what the problem was.
The project files as to be owned by the user tomcat6 in order to allow jenkins to update files on it. Seems that just belonging to the group which own the files isn't enough, even with 775 rights.
So a simple `sudo chown -R tomcat6:mygroup myproject` did solve the update problem

Comment: Any ideas on why it's not working with `775` rights? This is really strange and I'm also having the exact same issue.

Comment: i provide my folder an access of jenkin user and it started worrking
sudo chown -R jenkins MyFolder/